# How to make an appimage appear on aplications?

Tags: plank

I use a program called Stremio and I managed to download it and make the stremio.appimage file executable BUT I can't figure out how to get this file into Aplications. At the moment if I want to use the program I have to open Files and go to the folder where it is and click on it. BUT I want to be able to add it to aplications and to the dock.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the AppImage isn't creating a .desktop file for itself, so Elementary doesn't know it's available.

Never mind, there's an app in the AppCenter called "AppEditor", you can use that to create a new entry for your AppImage.